# Android Show Activity Title/status bar at the top after it is hidden

Tags: android, android-activity, statusbar

Currently in my `FragmentActivity`, I hide the status bar by, in the `onCreate` method, doing the following:

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

this works no problem.

But in full screen, say user clicks a button, I will want to swap in another fragment (remember we are in `FragmentActivity`), I mean replacing the currently fragment that is displayed in full screen.

but I want the titlebar/status to be shown.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it programmatically

Answer (score 23):

Here you can change your title bar dynamically using following two methods. I called them from my `Activity`. So to call from `Fragment` you need the `Activity` instance.

```
public void hideTitle() {
        try {
            ((View) findViewById(android.R.id.title).getParent())
                    .setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    public void showTitle() {
        try {
            ((View) findViewById(android.R.id.title).getParent())
                    .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

Comment: awesome mate !!!! cheers for your awesome answer !!! it should be the accepted answer !!

Comment: Thanks @Rudi .. answering becomes meaningful when i get this kind of inspiration :)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways of doing so:

**First Approach:**

[FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE)

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.foo_layout);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title_bar); 
or

youractivity.setTitle();
```

**NOTE!** you can include a simple `TextView` in side your layout `custom_title_bar`

Make you `custom_title_bar` layout as follows:

```
   <LinearLayout           
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
         style="@android:style/WindowTitle"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="TextView"
      />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Second Approach:**

[Activity.setTitle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
this.setTitle("My Title!");
```