# hide and show statusbar without any effect to layout in android

Tags: android, statusbar, ebook-reader

I want to write a book-reader application that normally runs in full-screen, but when user touched screen, status bar become visible OVER my main layout without re-creating the whole view.
I already read these but no help at all:

[Hide notification bar without using fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851162/hide-notification-bar-without-using-fullscreen)
[Hide Notification bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222713/hide-notification-bar)
[Android Show Activity Title/status bar at the top after it is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437786/android-show-activity-title-status-bar-at-the-top-after-it-is-hidden)

any idea how can I do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I did it!!
these 2 methods will show and hide status bar without destroying the layout.
you need to set

```
private View mMainView; // The main view of the activity

private int mSystemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
```

then

```
    /** Hides StatusBar and ActionBar */
private void hideSystemUi() {

    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.hide();

    // Set flags for hiding status bar
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    // Hide the status bar.
    mMainView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);}
```

and

```
   /** Shows StatusBar and ActionBar */
private void showSystemUi() {
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.show();
    // Reset flags 
    mMainView.setSystemUiVisibility(this.mSystemUiVisibility);
}
```

and put this in your onCreate() method:

```
mMainView = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
mMainView.setSystemUiVisibility(mSystemUiVisibility);
```

Comment: what is mSystemUiVisibility in showSystemUI method ?