# How to display countdown timer on status bar in android, like time display?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications, countdowntimer, android-statusbar

I am making an app which allows the user to pick a date and time. Once the date and time are reached,it will display an animation on the screen. Before its time, it will just show countdown time (like xxx:xx:xx) on screen. I achieved this using a textview which changes every second. How can I display this text on status bar, like time is displayed

I have tried using Notification constructor like in some post I found here but they are depricated and wont work anymore.
I tried with NotificationCompat.Builder but it doesnt really have a way to set text which could be displayed on status bar.

Anyone knows any work arpund solution for it, please give me an answer. I just need to display a text on status bar insted of icon

Comment: have you tried the setTicker method in the NotificationCompat.Builder class?

Comment: I have tried. The problem is that , as my notification text updates every second, setTicker will display it on notification bar every second with an animation(come from below)  which will be very annoying for the user

Comment: check out @Shazeel Afzal's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437786/android-show-activity-title-status-bar-at-the-top-after-it-is-hidden). Might be along the lines of what you are looking for

Comment: create a notification and use setSmallIcon(resId, level). update level with counter. Of course resId must be level list drawable and you must have all the numbers as images in the drawable folder

Comment: I think @uguboz is correct

Answer (score -2):

You can set CustomView on the ActionBar by passing a layout file or View. Here is a sample code.

```
protected void setCustomActionBarTitle(String title) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
            actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.layout_action_bar_title);
            TextView titleView = (TextView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
            titleView.setText(title);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.up_icon);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Add this in your activity_main xml file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/header_size"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:textColor="@color/title"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/header_size"
                android:textSize="@dimen/header_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text=""/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And in your activity add these lines

```
    actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back);
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
```

Now you can set the countdown timer in this textview, also align the TextView as required